# Is it safe to call unlock() on a lock which might have already been unlocked?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, reentrantreadwritelock

In this example:

```
private ReentrantReadWriteLock mLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public void method(boolean condition) {
    try {
        mLock.writelock.lock()

        if (condition) {
            mLock.writelock.unlock();
        }
    } finally {
        mLock.writelock.unlock();
    }
}
```

What happens when `mLock.writelock.unlock()` is called in the `finally` block if the unlock in the `if` statement has been executed?

Is this code safe or do I need to perform some check on whether there is a lock in place before attempting to unlock?

Comment: [What does the javadoc say?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock.html#unlock--)

Comment: You spent more time in forming this question than it wouldve taken to try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems very straight forward as per documentation, and it should throw `IllegalMonitorStateException` while re-executing `ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock.html#unlock`.

> Attempts to release this lock. If the current thread is the holder of
>   this lock then the hold count is decremented. If the hold count is now
>   zero then the lock is released. If the current thread is not the
>   holder of this lock then IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown.

[Documentation Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock.html#unlock--)

Enforce condition on finally unlock execution also which would escape from exception.